# Publish packages in jetbrain space npm registry offline

Tags: npm, jetbrains-fleet

Hi i'm trying to add all my deps and sub deps packages to my offline jetbrain space npm registry. How can i do this very fast?

For deps i download directy with npm pack and publish it but for sub deps i have a lot and i want to know if there is a way to download directly deps and sub deps